# Django-Haystack less than or equal to is not working properly

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using **django-haytsack** in my django-application. I have to filter Searchqueryset based on salary which is a integer field. Trying to filter using **lte** but its not giving proper result.

What I'm already tried:

models.py:

```py
class UserSkillsProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    salary = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

search_indexes.py:

```py
class UserSkillsProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   ...
   salary = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='salary',null=True)
```

Query:

```py
   search_models = [UserSkillsProfile]
   qs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('last_updated_time').filter(salary__lte=int(min_sal)).models(
                    *search_models)
```

When I give *min_sal* value as 5000 it returns results which salary greater than the *min_sal* also including the lesser value. I need to get the results lesser than 5000.

Comment: show your models.py code

Comment: I have added models.py code above